# How to get through one-block-high passages?

Tags: super-mario-bros-3

> [image: For the facepalm series.]
>
> *Mario needs a diet.*

There's not enough room to fill up the P meter, all the pipes are out of reach and no shells are coming my way. Am I screwed? (This is in [World 7-5.](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Bros._3/World_7#World_7-5))

Comment: I don't remember this level but the pic looks like you can crouch while running right to slide under the blocks.

Comment: I'm ashamed of you, badp. You're lucky I don't rescind my vote for this infraction.

Comment: @Nick This is my first play through ever of a Mario game! :(

Comment: You chose the right one to start with. Mario 3 is the [all-time peak of the platformer artform](http://www.actionbutton.net/?p=426).

Comment: @Brant, that article made my day.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Nope! What you need to do is back up a little, probably to the left edge of the screen against the wall, hold down Right+B in order to start running, then press Down to crouch just before you get to the blocks. Mario should then slide underneath the blocks and come out on the other side.

Comment: Physics existed in games before Flash. `;-)`